# Avoir vs. Posséder

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

Salut! I was watching a French TV show and a woman said "Il possède pas des animaux." That make me start thinking- when do you use avoir vs. posséder? Would you use posséder more to describe possession of physical things? Does it still make sense to say "Il n'a pas des animaux"?

Comment: Are you sure of the *des*? *Il possède pas d'animaux* would be more expected.

Comment: posséder means to own, avoir means to have. However, in French, you can "posséder" immaterial things, like goodness or intelligence (bonté). In English, also: he possesses a good deal of intelligence.

Comment: @jlliagre oh gosh why is it d’ if it’s plural?

Comment: Because of the negation. Most of the times, *des* becomes *de* in negative sentences: *Il a **des** cheveux blancs* →  *Il n'a pas **de** cheveux blancs*.

Answer (score 1):

You generally use *posséder* for something that has some value, that is part of your wealth, often something that you bought, earned or inherited.

*Avoir* doesn't imply anything like that although it can always be used instead of *posséder*.

For example, if you rent a car, you can say *j'ai une voiture rouge* but not *je possède une voiture rouge*.

I believe the difference is the same than the one between *to own* and *to have* however, sometimes *posséder* is used for something that still has some value but isn't material; e.g. *Il possède un don pour la musique* (He is gifted in music.)